# How To use MouseClicked event to prevent mouseExited event?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseclick-event

I've got a simple java swing code where a text field changes when the button is hovered over and clicked, but when i use a variable to deactivate the mouseExited event, it does not work and continues to change the text field. I think its to do with the variable only being available to the mouseClicked event? How would i fix this. Thanks

my imports are java.awt and javax.swing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean check = true;
        JFrame f =new JFrame("ActionListener Example");  
        JTextField tf = new JTextField("You should press button 1");  
        tf.setBounds(100,100, 150,20);  
        JButton b=new JButton("Click Here");  
        b.setBounds(50,100,60,30);  
        //2nd step
        b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            tf.setText("you did it");
            boolean check = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            tf.setText("DO IT!");   
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)  {
            if (check) {
                tf.setText("You should press the button");
                }
        }});
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.add(b);
        f.add(tf);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think its to do with the variable only being available to the mouseClicked event? How would i fix this.

Then don't define a second "check" variable in the mouseClicked method.

```
//boolean check = false;
check = false;
```

Edit:

> Local variable check defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Start be rewriting your entire class to give it a better structure.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Download the `ButtonDemo` code and modify it.

The demo code will show you how to structure your code so that

1. all the code is NOT contained in the main() method:
2. you use layout managers
3. you create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)
4. your class can use "instance" variables, instead of a local variable. You "check" variable will be an instance variable.

Comment: "Local variable check defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"
im not sure how to fix this either, thanks though

Comment: @MyCupOfTea, see edit. Note Keep a link to the tutorial handy. It contains examples of most Swing basics.

Comment: Thanks! I deactivated the button instead and that worked out, using if b.isEnabled instead of check

Comment: @MyCupOfTea, . Your code structure is flawed and will lead to problems in the future. So even if you decide to enable/disable the button, your code still needs to be rewritten.